# XCode 12.4 : An Internal Error Occurred Editing functionality may be limited

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Since upgrading to XCode12.4 on two different MacBooks both running macOS 10.15.6 I have issues opening Storyboard / Xib files.

Just to be clear this doesn't occur for a specific project - this happens for *any* project I open and for *any* storyboard / xib file within that project.

There is a long delay before the file opens and when it does I see.

1. The UI Components in blue outline rather than the details.
2. The Error Message: An Internal Error Occurred Editing functionality may be limited

From my log.txt

```
XCODE VERSION INFO:

Version = 12.4 (12D4e)
Plugin Version = 17701
Beta Version = 1
OS Version = 10.15.6 (19G2021)


ASSERTION:

Failed to update scene '01J-lp-oVM' with IBUIViewAutolayoutGuide (x1), UIView (x1), and UIViewController (x1).

Exception name: IBPlatformToolFailureException
Exception reason: The tool closed the connection

Application Specific Information:
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create remote render context'

terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone Xʀ (9B855293-1F8D-4794-BF54-5193C46BB094) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone Xʀ
```

I've cleaned derived data / restarted my machine etc - all to no avail.

All I can do at this stage is reinstall XCode 12.4 unless anyone can make any suggestions?

Comment: Couldn't find a resolution to this within a reasonable amount of time so ended up reinstalling. Seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a new mac with apple silicon, try to uncheck `Open using Rosetta`.

[image]

Comment: I tried to search with this error. Many forum old posts are telling to delete Derived Data and so more other stuffs. Nothing works. Your just simple solution works for me. 
Thank You Very much #Myungjin Choi
God bless you

Answer (score 4):

Close the xcode and simulator and run this command on the terminal

This will help to remove storyboard loading errors

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

Comment: also, eject cable from the device if it's connected